# How could I approach N times sum of 3 numbers?

Tags: c#

More detail about the problem, I had the task to program the sequence 1 2 3 and the sum of the last 3 numbers N times, so it would be like 1 2 3 6 11 20 37. I approached it like this

```
static void Main()
        {
            BigInteger cont;
            BigInteger MAX = 2020202020202020;
            BigInteger[] Numberstrack = { 1, 2, 3 };
            BigInteger sum = 0;
            for (cont = 3; cont < MAX; cont++)
            {
                sum = Numberstrack[0] + Numberstrack[1] + Numberstrack[2];
                Numberstrack[0] = Numberstrack[1];
                Numberstrack[1] = Numberstrack[2];
                Numberstrack[2] = sum;
                Console.WriteLine(cont);//just to know how much is it going and how fast
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Numero " + cont + ": " + sum.ToString().Substring(sum.ToString().Length - 4));
        }
```

You can see the number I need to get is absurd large but that's why I wanna know, if someone know about other way to approach this problem and probably not to wait  for 1+ hour to get the result.

PD : If you ask, why I started in cont 3, its because this sequence starts really with [0, 1, 0] and a clue in the problem was that the 30th position was the 45152016.

PD2: I had to use System.Numerics.BigInteger to handle the big numbers.
Thanks all and have a nice day.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `cont` which is bounded by your bigint and not `sum`? If it is `sum`, you should get there quite quickly.

Comment: 100% sure it is, it was way more slow when i printed the sum so i changend so could know just the position.

Comment: Can you help me with an expected output on how it should look like, This is because the output of your code snippet look different from the output format(1 2 3 6 11 20 37) that you have shown in your question.

Comment: thats becouse in the code i printed only the position the sequences is at, if you wanna see the secuence you have to print "sum" not "cont".

Comment: This is something like fibonacci but defined as `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)` and `f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2`

Comment: @RidexOujiNekoMárquez Please [edit] your post to include the actual question you want to ask. Also include a description of the problem you have.

Comment: @Progman i don't really undestand what you are asking me, the problem is explained in the question and thats the actual question i wanna ask, another solution for the same problem.

Comment: @RidexOujiNekoMárquez You have not written a question inside your text (only in the title) or what the problem is. For the long runtime, notice that you try to run a `for()` loop with 2 quadrillion iterations. That's a lot of calculations/runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@amk was on the right lines, but you need to increase your elements to 4.

I did a series of experiments gradually optimising the code.  By way of warning I only ran 5 tries of 300,000 iterations, simply because I did not want to chew up my PC all day.  I advise you to repeat my tests yourself.

Firstly I ran your code as is: I got an average of 8,310 milliseconds.

Next I replaced your BigInteger[] with three variables, a, b and c.  This brought a small (expected) gain, with an average run of 8,214 milliseconds.

Now I tried a variant of @amk, but with the required 4 variables, and also with running the iteration in batches of four.  This got the average down to 7,768 milliseconds.

Finally I replaced the multiplication by 2 with a left shift, leaving me with a final average of 7,247 milliseconds, i.e. over a second faster than the original.

My last code looks like this:

```
static void leftShift()
{
    BigInteger cont;
    BigInteger MAX = 300000;
    BigInteger a = 1;
    BigInteger b = 2;
    BigInteger c = 3;
    BigInteger d = 6;

    BigInteger sum = 0;
    for (cont = 4; cont < (MAX - 3); cont += 4)
    {
        a = (d << 1) - a;
        b = (a << 1) - b;
        c = (b << 1) - c;
        d = (c << 1) - d;
    }
    sum = d;
    if (cont < MAX)
    {
        a = (d << 1) - a;
        sum = a;
        cont++;
    }
    if (cont < MAX)
    {
        b = (a << 1) - b;
        sum = b;
        cont++;
    }
    if (cont < MAX)
    {
        c = (b << 1) - c;
        sum = c;
        cont++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Numero " + cont + ": " + sum.ToString());
}
```

I only wrote to the Console at the end of the operation, plus a separate print of the time taken.

In my case (using 300,000) I did not need the extra tests at the end, since 300,000 is exactly divisible by 4, but I put them in for completeness' sake in case a MAX is used that is not so convenient!

As a final aside, what was particularly interesting, was that with each optimisation the standard deviation of my results fell dramatically (818.7, 485.7, 129.4 and finally 38.2).  I am sure that one of the experts here can explain that.  To the mind of a mere mortal, though, it does confirm to me that my optimisations were also theoretically sound (as well as a practical improvement).

Answer (score 0):

For i-th number we have:

A(i-1)*2-a(i-4)

I is greater than 4 becuz we must have the first 4 numbers.

Comment: i don't understand where should be N and where the first 4 numbers that you mension, can you explain??

Comment: you have a starting stack f numbers which are: {1,2,3,6}, these are a[0-4], so for the next a[5] we have a[5]=a[4]*2 -a[0] we simply remove the first stack from the final result. with this you can solve the problem set like Fibonacci.

Comment: what i don't understand is the formula, i know the 4 numbers are from the sequence but how can i implement that in the code??

Comment: you should keep your 4 numbers and after the calculation remove the first one and add result on top of it. for the next number use the formula it's the fastest way or you can simply add the stack together pop the last one and add the result to the top

Comment: `sum = Numberstrack[2]*2-Numberstrack[0];`  that's it and if you remove the console log it would run faster for the final result.

Comment: Well i tried it and the secuence i get is 1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55 when it has to be 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 20, 37, 68, 125. I'll try that console log that you mention.